# Check if product available in Shopify using javascript

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

I have a javascript that handles the product listing on the collection page. Is there a way to ensure that the product is available and not out of stock. I need something similar to `{% if product.available %}`. But I don't want to change the `.liquid` file. I need it in `Javascript`.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the JSON representation of an arbitrary product in your store by fetching data from `/products/<some-product-handle>.js`.  When using the `.js` endpoint, the product object will include a number of aggregate parameters, including `product.available` which will be `true` if at least 1 variant in the product is available.

Note that Shopify has 2* different product representations, one at the `/products/<some-product-handle>.js` endpoint and one at the `/products/<some-product-handle.json` endpoint.  These two objects are surprisingly different, and one of those differences is that the `.json` endpoint does not have the aggregate `product.available` value - you would have to determine that yourself by checking the availability of all the variants within if using this endpoint. This is one of the reasons why I generally recommend using the `.js` endpoint for all your Javascript needs.

---

*** *Strictly speaking, there's actually 3 different product representations: the output from a `{{ product | json }}` drop from Liquid is slightly different from both endpoints but largely the same as the `.js` endpoint, with the exception being how the `product.options` array is structured*

Answer (score 1):

You have four options for getting data into javascript in Shopify:

- If the javascript is included as an inline script tag / a snippet in the liquid file then you’d be writing javascript liquid and you can interpolate directly e.g. `var product = "{{ product | json}}"`.
- You can update the liquid document to include e.g. attributes with the required data, e.g ‘data-‘ attributes, and then read those with javascript from the document. You’ve said this is not an option.
- Re-fetch some data about entities on the current page using a Shopify API: e.g Ajax / Storefront / Shopify Buy SDK.
- Add an alternative liquid page for an existing theme page that formats the data you need to json (e.g. `{{ product | json }}`) but name it e.g. product.ajax.liquid - this will make it into a custom view. Then you can fetch this pages url with the query parameter `?view=ajax` and returned document will include the rendered json. This effectively creates a custom API for you.

Those are the options.